# Recursive Palindrome

Tags: java

First of all I am not telling anyone to "do my homework." I just need a little help on how to keep repeating a process. This is the program I did below and it has a tester class with it.

The class:

```
class RecursivePalindrome {
    public static boolean isPal(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
            return true;
        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
            return isPal(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then the tester class which has the main method:

```
public class RecursivePalindromeTester {   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RecursivePalindrome  Pal = new RecursivePalindrome ();

        boolean quit = true;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word to test whether it is a palindrome or not(press quit to end.): ");
        String x = in.nextLine();
        while(quit) {
            boolean itsPal = Pal.isPal(x);
            if(itsPal == true){
                System.out.println(x + " is a palindrome.");
                quit = false;
            }
            else if (x.equals("quit")) {
                quit = false;
            }
            else {
                quit = false;
                System.out.println(x + " is not a palindrome.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This program find if the letter is Palindrome or not. I got all the calculations and stuff in but what do i do to keep asking the user for input and every time the user inputs it says if it is a Palindrome word or not.

Comment: Using consistent indentation levels would make your code much more readable -- to yourself, and to others.

Comment: How would i put in a ignoreCase so when the user inputs it ignores case

Comment: @user2059140:- You can use the ToUpper() method to change the string to all the Caps. Updated in my answer as well.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap with another while loop.

Look into the ***continue*** and ***break*** statements. They are very helpful for loops, which is what you're looking for information on here.
public class RecursivePalindromeTester {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        RecursivePalindrome  Pal = new RecursivePalindrome ();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
             System.out.print("Enter a word to test whether it is a palindrome or not(press quit to end.): ");
             String x = in.nextLine();
                boolean itsPal = Pal.isPal(x);
                if(itsPal == true){
                    System.out.println(x + " is a palindrome.");
                } else if (x.equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(x + " is not a palindrome.");
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just move the lines asking for user input and reading it:

```
System.out.print("Enter a word to test whether it is a palindrome or not(press quit to end.): ");
String x = in.nextLine();
```

...*into* your loop, e.g., just after the

```
while (quit) {
```

...line.

---

Side note: `quit` seems like an odd name for a boolean which, when `true`, means you *keep going*. :-)

Comment: Yes but if i put true the output will keep repeating but i need to repeat the question every time and give a result every time.

Comment: @user2059140: That's what moving those lines into the loop would achieve. I've clarified what lines I was talking about, and where to move them.

Comment: I did but same thing. Once i press in one input and the program shows one result and that's it ends there.

Comment: One more thing, could you please tell me how to put in a ignoreCase in there. Because when i put Racecar it says its not a Pali but when i put racecar it says it is.